# How to register a Visio class on a machine where it is not installed?

Tags: c#, visio

I have a task to create empty Visio document file (.vsd) with single page in it and drop few shapes there. My problem is that I have to write Windows console application for this purpose and it must run in the server environment where Visio is not installed. Is it possible to do that?

If I run application  on my development environment, new instance of Visio is started. But, on my server, where my application must run, Visio is not installed and Visio application launch will fail. What I can do in this situation?

Edit: Getting Visio installed on servers is not an option.

Comment: You will need to use the office `COM` objects, by not installed I suspect you mean not licenced? Easiest and quickest way for both you and whoever has assigned you with the task is to get Visio installed.

Comment: Getting Visio installed on servers is not an option

Comment: As I said, it's the quickest and easiest option. If the reason is that you don't have the licence, then you will not be able to do this either because you need access to the Office COM objects

Answer (score 1):

If you're not tied to binary, then I would use Visio's xml format - vdx.  Saveen Reddy has a great library (including NuGet) that makes life very simple - see

- [VisioAutomation.VDX](http://visioautomation.codeplex.com/)

Also, Visio 2013 now uses a new package (zip style) file format - see:

- [VSDX: the new Visio file format](http://blogs.office.com/b/visio/archive/2012/09/10/vsdx-the-new-visio-file-format.aspx)
- [10 tips for developers working with the Visio VSDX file format](http://blogs.office.com/b/visio/archive/2013/01/29/10-tips-for-developers-working-with-the-visio-vsdx-file-format.aspx)

All of the above will enable you to generate Visio documents without having the application installed.